# What are additional responsibilities that a coordinating manager can take up?

Tags: team-management, communication, project-team

I am working as a coordinator for two teams situated in different time zones. I do everything that is related to coordination (arrange meetings, doing scrum updates across teams, adding clarification etc).

But I am very interested to know what additional responsibilities I could take up as project coordinator, that benefit both the teams, but benefit more the team I am representing (say Team A), other than the usual coordination work.

*Misc info:*

- I do not have any reportees to me, there are PMs who takes care of people/project management for Team A and Team B.
- I do not have any control over the project.
- I have a feeling that if I keep doing this for a year or more, my skill levels are going to be underutilized and may be of no value.
- I might be understating my role, as it sometimes involve a complex of coordination of work for 12 people at site B and 6 people at Site A (where I am located representing Team B) and spend a lot of time to carefully read and assimilate and reply to emails.
- But I do get spurts of 2-8 hours a week to do something else for the project.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a project management question (yet), and I suspect that it is too localized for the site.  I don't think it should be closed, but I do think it should be generalized somehow.

Comment: Hi oneworld, I submitted an [edit]. Can you take a look at your second paragraph again? I wasn't 100% sure I understood what you were saying and want to make sure I didn't break anything. Please edit further if that isn't what you meant to say in paragraph 2. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That's right, thanks jmort253

Answer (score 2):

Your team will know better than us what additional responsibilities you could help them with. What is going well? What isn't going well? What hurdles or small things trip them up during the week? If you are looking to add value to your team, ask them. We will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Improve communications within your project team. Identify resource requirements that you can personally fulfill.

### Problems

1. Your roles and responsibilities within your current project are either ill-defined or simply not challenging enough for you.
2. Communications on your project team are poor, or you would be asking this question within your team rather than on the Internet.

### Potential Solutions from a Project Management Perspective

A good project plan clearly defines goals and success criteria for the team and for its individual members. If your project plan does *not* include these things, then it's a conversation that should be held with the project management team.

A properly-functioning project team has effective mechanisms for reporting status and identifying current resource requirements. If you want more to do, those artifacts are the ones to look at. If you don't have such artifacts on your project, this is another conversation that should be held with the project management team.

### Everything Else

Any other issues from your original question should either be raised with your supervisor or manager, or perhaps with Human Resources. Generic career growth and individual responsibility on a specific project are topics that are highly localized, and not really project management questions *per se*.